# React value fetching from flask

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask

here I got an Array of objects in res,
but when I set the data in State the result is an empty array.

```
 const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState([])

  function getData() {
    axios.get("http://192.168.29.72:5002/profile",)
    .then((response) => {
      const res =response.data

      setProfileData(res)
      console.log(profileData);
   
    }).catch((error) => {
      if (error.response) { 
        console.log(error.response)
        console.log(error.response.status)
        console.log(error.response.headers)
        }
    })}
```

Whats wrong here? how can I get the data in state.

Comment: hi, do you receive any error message? please share the context where `getData` is called

Comment: there is no error, only getting an empty array

Comment: in devtools > network have you verified that the call to the resource `http://192.168.29.72:5002/profile` is made? please share the context where you call the getData function

Comment: I dint get you, but now empty array is getting empty only in the first click , after that from next click onwards values are getting perfectly.

Comment: why values are empty in first click?

Comment: Stop logging unless you need to